# Dynamic element specification in CALL TRANSFORMATION

Tags: xml, dynamic, transformation, abap

I am using call transformation to convert XML to ABAP structure.

```
call transformation demo_id_upper_lower "id 
parameters mode = 'UP' 
source xml asxml_str 
result paymentrequest = abap_out.
```

This works as expected and the data is mapped to ABAP structure successfully. `paymentrequest` is the root tag ins this example.

Is there a way to specify a variable containing the tag name instead of the tag directly in the result?

```
data(my_var) = 'paymentrequest'. 

call transformation demo_id_upper_lower "id 
parameters mode = 'UP' 
source xml asxml_str 
result my_var = abap_out.
```

In this case there's no exception but variable is not resolved to value and I think it reads it literally.

Note: I have also tried assigning the element name to a field symbol. But that too didn't work.

Comment: Yes, you can. That's just explained in the [ABAP documentation](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcall_transformation.htm), see **RESULT (rtab)**

Comment: And what do you need it for? You wanna change callable transformation dynamically where your transformation have different parameter names?

Comment: Yes sort of, the root element will differ with the input xml string. The method I'm trying to design should be able to transform/map the given xml to the given abap structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's this [answer to your question, in this other ABAP forum](https://answers.sap.com/questions/563009/dynamic-element-specification-in-call-transformati.html).

```
data(res_tab) = value abap_trans_resbind_tab( ( name = root value = ref #( abap_out ) ) ).

call transformation demo_id_upper_lower "id
      parameters mode = 'UP'
      source xml asxml_str
      result (res_tab).

if result_tab is not initial.
   read table result_tab into data(result_wa) index 1.
    if sy-subrc = 0.
     assign result_wa-value->* to field-symbol(<abap_out>).
      if <abap_out> is assigned.
        abap_out = <abap_out>.
      endif.
     endif.
   endif.
```

Note, that the code given in this forum implements my very first "comment" two days ago, cf **RESULT (rtab)** in the [ABAP documentation of CALL TRANSFORMATION](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcall_transformation.htm).

Comment: Yes, that was the solution to my problem. I have incorporated the solution in my code; you can find the same in my comment to the anwer in that forum. Thanks!